# Importing Maven dependency

Tags: maven, gradle

I'm trying to include [ViewPagerIndicator](http://www.viewpagerindicator.com) into my project and I'd rather use the Maven dependency rather than importing the android library project. There's some code posted for maven

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.viewpagerindicator</groupId>
  <artifactId>library</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.1</version>
  <type>apklib</type>
</dependency>
```

and inside the sample project, that code is in a pom.xml file, but I don't have that file. Can I translate the above code into my build.gradle file? Or can I just create a pom.xml file and put it in my project?

Comment: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130003/using-viewpagerindicator-library-with-android-studio-and-gradle

Answer (score 3):

You should ask the author JakeWharton to make an aar available on Maven Central. (vote here: https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/pull/229). Until then there is a temporary solution to use maven repo from community.

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://github.com/Goddchen/mvn-repo/raw/master/'
    }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:viewpagerindicator:2.4.1'
}
```

https://github.com/Goddchen/mvn-repo

Comment: Sorry, the URL for the maven repository no longer works - check out this answer with the new repo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130003/using-viewpagerindicator-library-with-android-studio-and-gradle

Comment: Someone uploaded it to maven central directly. `compile 'com.mcxiaoke.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1'`

Answer (score 0):

You will find the file in [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.viewpagerindicator%7Clibrary%7C2.4.1%7Capklib) which means simple run the build and the file will be downloaded. This is also true for gradle where it looks like this:

```
'com.viewpagerindicator', name: 'library', version: '2.4.1', ext: 'apklib'
```