# adding ViewPagerIndicator via maven in Android Studio

Tags: android, maven

I'd like to use ViewPagerIndicator in my project, but for some reason it does not work.

Here is project top level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
       mavenCentral()
   }
   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
   }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

and here is module build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
compileSdkVersion 17
buildToolsVersion '19.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 18
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')
    compile files('libs/greendao-1.3.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/TestFlightLib.jar')
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1'
}
```

After this I hit Sync project with graddle files and all I get is "support-v4-r7" file in External Libraries.
Am I doing anything wrong please?

Thank you :)

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130003/using-viewpagerindicator-library-with-android-studio-and-gradle#comment31843513_21130070) comment

Comment: Thanks, it will be probably it. That it is not moved in gradle structure :/