# How add ViewPagerIndicator to android studio

Tags: android

I see this link [Using ViewPagerIndicator library with Android Studio and Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130003/using-viewpagerindicator-library-with-android-studio-and-gradle) and here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+"
    compile('com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }

}
```

And gradle build has successfully completed .But i can't import `com.viewpagerindicator.PageIndicator`
 .I also check `.gradle` folder and viewpager folder already exist.Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add library in Android Studio by File -> Project structure... -> Libriaries (or Modules)?

Answer (score 0):

Use the **full file path** to the location of the jar. That's worked for me every time. If you're using Android Studio make sure to 'Sync Project with Gradle Files' and rebuild as well.