# Add ViewPagerIndicator to Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, viewpagerindicator

i'm trying to get Jake Wharton's ViewPagerIndicator working with Android Studio but unfortunately it won't work. 
I downloaded the .aar file from [here](https://bintray.com/populov/maven/com.viewpagerindicator%3alibrary) and included it in my libs folder. 
I referenced it like this:

```
compile files('src/main/libs/viewpagerindicator_2.4.1.aar')
```

Android Studio gives me the following error:

```
Error:duplicate files during packaging of APK
```

I'm not very familiar with gradle and don't know what to do when it gives me this error. 
Can you please help me with this one?

Here's my complete build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
     release {
     runProguard false
     proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.0.0'
    compile files('src/main/libs/PdfViewer.jar')
    compile files('src/main/libs/viewpagerindicator_2.4.1.aar')
}
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Based on the [answer given by Jürgen 'Kashban' Wahlmann](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26138635/1525990), it is now possible to add ViewPagerIndicator via gradle:

Top Level Build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

App's build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
```

Also, based on the [answer given by Enrico Susatyo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35761063/1525990) now it seems possible to download the library from Jitpack maven repositories. Do it as follows:

In root build.grade:

```
allprojects {
        repositories {
            ...
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        }
    }
```

In project build.grade:

```
dependencies {
            compile 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'
    }
```

**------------**

To use Android-ViewPagerIndicator in Android Studio, you can’t download it from gradle. Instead, you must import the library as an “Existing Project” to your current one.

Follow these steps:

#1 Download [source code](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) from GitHub.

#2 In your Android Studio Project: 
File -> Project Structure -> add (+ symbol) -> Import Existing Project. Import just the folder called ”library”, not the entire project (leave the import options as Android Studio suggests).

# 3 If the "compileSdkVersion" specified in your build.gradle doesn’t match with the one specified in the Android-ViewPagerIndicator project, change the second one. The same apply with any other property, such as "minSdkVersion" or even the current support library.

# 4 Add Android-ViewPagerIndicator project as a dependency to your build.gradle module:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':library')
}
```

# 5 Sync project with gradle files.

Comment: Yes it is working fine & rest of the answers is not working & either not in new android studio. +1 Thanks

Comment: The only answer out of hundred ones which is really working. Thanks

Comment: you should use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35761063/1332549) at 2016

Comment: This no longer works (currently December 2021) since bintray has been shut down. But there is a GitHub issue that provides a drop-in replacement: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/issues/415

Answer (score 66):

It can be imported by Gradle like this:

Top Level Build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

In your App's build.gradle add this to your dependencies section:

```
compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
```

(Add @aar to avoid "packaging for apklib is not supported error")

Works fine for me.

Comment: Great work! This answer should be marked as "Right".

Comment: "Failed to resolve: com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1" error occured when i tried this

Comment: @RctLynx I didn't check this in a while.... still seems to be the correct version number. But with the new design support library it is no longer necessary to include the custom ViewPager Indicator (https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v4)

Comment: In my test the first reference to the maven url in `buildscript repositories` is unnecessary, only the second usage in the `allprojects repositories` section is necessary.

Answer (score 44):

As of today (March 2016), Jitpack's maven repos work for me: https://jitpack.io/#JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/2.4.1/aar

In root `build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
        repositories {
            ...
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        }
    }
```

In project `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
            compile 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'
    }
```

Comment: Really helpful. Friends please note for support your application minimum sdk should 11. (just hints for fresher )

Answer (score 1):

**You can do it without any third party library**

**Final Result:**

[image]

1) Use frame layout as a container for Viewpager and then add a Linearlayout at the bottom of it.

```
<FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/product_images_pager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/indicator_root"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                    </LinearLayout>
                </HorizontalScrollView>

            </FrameLayout>
```

2) Define size and margin for indicators

```
  //define globaly 
   private LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageParam;

   //init params
      int margin = Utils.pxFromDp(getActivity(), 5);
        int width = Utils.pxFromDp(getActivity(), 8);
        imageParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, width);
        imageParam.setMargins(margin, margin, margin, margin);
```

3) Add Indicators in Linear Layout

```
 for (int indicatorCount = 0; indicatorCount < productFromShoppingList.getProductImages().size();
             indicatorCount++) {

            ImageView imageIndicator =
                    new ImageView(getActivity());

            imageIndicator.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            imageIndicator.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            imageIndicator.setLayoutParams(imageParam);

            indicatorContainer.addView(imageIndicator);
            indicators.add(imageIndicator);
            imageIndicator.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.indicator_unselected);
        }
```

4) Initialize indicator at 0 position

```
 indicators.get(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.indicator_unselected);
```

5) Update indicator on view pager page change

```
carousalViewPager.setAdapter(new slidingPagerAdapter(getActivity(),
            productFromShoppingList.getProductImages()));

    carousalViewPager
            .addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int position,
                                           float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                    currentPageIndex = position;
                    updateIndicators(currentPageIndex);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                }
            });


private void updateIndicators(int selectedPostion) {
    for (int indicatorPosition = 0; indicatorPosition < indicators.size(); indicatorPosition++) {
        indicators.get(indicatorPosition).setBackgroundResource(indicatorPosition == selectedPostion ? R.drawable.indicator_selected
                : R.drawable.indicator_unselected);
    }
}
```

Last but not least add this 2 drawable for indicator

**indicator_unselected.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/white" />
</shape>
```

**indicator_selected.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <corners android:radius="100dp" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

Comment: indicatorContainer and indicators not initialize.

Comment: indicatorContainer  variable is Linear Layout of indicator_root in Java Code. indicators is empty array of ImageView

Answer (score 0):

For me trying to integrate it from maven didn't work out. I always go the following build exceptions and styles couldn't be reoslved:

> no ressource found that matches the given name vpiCirclePageIndicatorStyle vpiTitlePageIndicatorStyle

Adding the dependency via jitpack works just perfect:

In root `build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
        repositories {
            ...
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        }
    }
```

In project `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
            compile 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'
    }
```