# Error setting up LinePageIndicator inside Fragment - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator, activity-indicator

I am using Jake Wharton's `ViewPagerIndicator` to add a `LinePageIndicator` within my `ViewPager`. The problem I am having is that when I follow his **Usage** instructions I get the following errors **(Cannot resolve method 'findViewById(int)' & 'getSupportFragmentManager()')** in this area:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lay_menufragment, container, false);

        //galeria de imagenes

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.addfragments(PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(imagenes[0]));
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.addfragments(PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(imagenes[1]));
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.addfragments(PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(imagenes[2]));

        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        //Set the pager with an adapter
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

        //Bind the title indicator to the adapter
        LinePageIndicator lineIndicator = (LinePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.lines);
        lineIndicator.setViewPager(pager);

        return rootView;

    }
```

Here is the full code of my `Fragment`:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import com.viewpagerindicator.LinePageIndicator;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FmMenu extends Fragment {

    int[] imagenes = {
            R.drawable.jeans,
            R.drawable.blusas,
            R.drawable.leggings,
    };

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lay_menufragment, container, false);

        //galeria de imagenes

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.addfragments(PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(imagenes[0]));
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.addfragments(PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(imagenes[1]));
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.addfragments(PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(imagenes[2]));

        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        //Set the pager with an adapter
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

        //Bind the title indicator to the adapter
        LinePageIndicator lineIndicator = (LinePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.lines);
        lineIndicator.setViewPager(pager);

        return rootView;

    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        List<Fragment> fragmentos;
        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            fragmentos = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        }

        public void addfragments(Fragment xfragment){
            fragmentos.add(xfragment);
        }


        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return fragmentos.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragmentos.size();
        }


    }


    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

        private static final String ARG_IMAGE = "imagen";
        private int imagen;

        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int imagen) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_IMAGE, imagen);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            fragment.setRetainInstance(true);
            return fragment;
        }

        public void onClick(View v){

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if(getArguments() != null) {
                imagen = getArguments().getInt(ARG_IMAGE);
            }
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);

            ImageView mainimages = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            mainimages.setImageResource(imagen);

            mainimages.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent activityIntent = new Intent();

                    Intent intent = new Intent();

                    switch(imagen){
                        case R.drawable.jeans:
                            intent = new Intent(getActivity(), JeansActivity.class);
                            break;
                        case R.drawable.blusas:
                            intent = new Intent(getActivity(), BlusasActivity.class);
                            break;
                        case R.drawable.leggings:
                            intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LeggingsActivity.class);
                            break;
                    }

                    startActivity(intent);

                }


            });

            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

I also get the following error in my layout when I implement `com.viewpagerindicator.LinePageIndicator`:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/viewpagerindicator/R$attr
    at com.viewpagerindicator.LinePageIndicator.<init>(LinePageIndicator.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:413)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:105)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallback.loadView(LayoutlibCallback.java:176)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:214)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:142)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:806)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:809)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:809)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:413)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:321)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:708)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:697)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:932)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:697)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.render(RenderService.java:816)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:480)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is my full XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/container">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView3" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="515dp">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="227dp"
                tools:context=".FmMenu"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />

            <com.viewpagerindicator.LinePageIndicator
                android:id="@+id/lines"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:background="@drawable/note"
                android:layout_below="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="39dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="SELECCIONA TU PRODUCTO:"
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:textColor="#ffdd190d"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:typeface="monospace" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I used this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25702884/add-viewpagerindicator-to-android-studio) to add `ViewPagerIndicator` via `Gradle`

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is that a library or are you just using the class in your project?

Comment: @BojanKseneman If you are mentioning about `ViewPagerindicator` then yes, it is a library that I added via `Gradle` in the link I mentioned below. When I added it, I put the `<com.viewpagerindicator.LinePageIndicator` code in my XML layout and binded the indicators to my `ViewPager` and that is where I get those errors.