# Attribute "raduis" has already been defined

Tags: java, android

I add **[ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator)** library using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25702884/add-viewpagerindicator-to-android-studio) question.

And I get "**Attribute "radius" has already been defined**" error

I have not idea about what to do for fix this error, I searched in internet but I cant get the answer. Here is my gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile project(':vksdk_library')
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'


    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: @Android777 it doesn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had this error.  I use ViewPageIndicator like this:

```
 <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:id="@+id/page_indicator"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    app:centered="true"
                    app:fillColor="@color/white"
                    app:radius="4dp"
                    app:snap="false"
                    />
```

Here is my solution, I change `xmlns:app` to `xmlns:vpi` ,and all `app` namespace in this `CirclePageIndicator` element to `vpi`, the problem solved. Below is the code after changed:

```
<com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
     xmlns:vpi="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/page_indicator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                vpi:centered="true"
                vpi:fillColor="@color/white"
                vpi:radius="4dp"
                vpi:snap="false"
                />
```

Answer (score 3):

check **[this](https://www.google.com.mx/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fp%2Fandroid%2Fissues%2Fdetail%3Fid%3D76828&ei=UXxWVfD_KMHSsAXbyIGoBg&usg=AFQjCNGiWAANJDgFAEXL8oYYFWseVRP8dQ&sig2=e1hwh5J-7oMBXjnt4L8Rtw&bvm=bv.93564037,d.b2w)**

"I've added two libraries into my project. The two projects have declared attribute called "radius", when I run the project I got the following error."

```
Error:Attribute "radius" has already been defined
```

> The issue is that there is a single namespace for all resource names
>   and both libraries are colliding. This is clearly not great at all, I
>   understand your frustrations, but until the platform implements the
>   ability to have different resource pools inside an app there's little
>   the tools can do.

Comment: How exactly can I do it?