# Failed to Resolve Maven library

Tags: android, gradle

Android Studio is being itself, and I am getting a very weird error.

In my app.gradle, I add the following line in dependencies {..} :

```
compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:parent:2.4.@+aar'
```

when i build the gradle, I get an error in "Messages"

```
Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.viewpagerindicator:parent:2.4.
<a href="openFile">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

Now for the weird part :

Same library (same version 2.4.@+aar) is in my dependencies of another project on same Android Studio window/instance and it works like a charm.

What is going on? Your suggestions/resolution/experience on the problem are most welcome-

**EDIT**

New Error on gradle build:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Artifact 'library.aar (com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1)' not found.
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/viewpagerindicator/library/2.4.1/library-2.4.1.aar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to hit search location URL in browser you will find that there is no such resource available.

Jake Wharton hasn't released it in maven as an aar. You can find the detailed description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130003/using-viewpagerindicator-library-with-android-studio-and-gradle) & [here](https://github.com/hzsweers/SUREwalk_android/blob/master/surewalk/build.gradle)

Comment: Have you gone through the links?? You need to make some additional changes in your build.gradle

Comment: Beautiful. I got it. adding  maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
    mavenCentral() to top level gradle. thanks man.