# How to create start / onboarding cards for an Android like Google Apps?

Tags: android

The product managers that I work with would like to create a whats new start cards on first launch of the android application.  I would like to know what is the recommended approach for this and any example code. 
The cards will be images with text overlaid on top.  I want a left and right swipe navigation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Using ViewPagerIndicator library with Android Studio and Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130003/using-viewpagerindicator-library-with-android-studio-and-gradle)

I was trying to reproduce the dot navigation for on boarding screens.