# Viewpagerindicator Android studio

Tags: android, gradle, viewpagerindicator

How do I add the library to my project? I downloaded the module from this website. http://viewpagerindicator.com/#download.
I have tried changing the gradle file to

```
 buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" } // for viewpagerindicator
  }
}

repositories {
  maven { url 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' } // for viewpagerindicator
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.githang:viewpagerindicator:2.4.2@aar'
}
```

and still i get the following error: "Didn't find class com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator"

Thank you for any help

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/q/21130003/5829906](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21130003/5829906) Check these answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the library from site and include as library project in gradle.

```
compile project(":nameofproject")
```