# Importing Module in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

How can I import an external module (named ViewPagerIndicator) in Android Studio?

Comment: Follow : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130003/using-viewpagerindicator-library-with-android-studio-and-gradle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using ViewPagerIndicator library with Android Studio and Gradle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130003/using-viewpagerindicator-library-with-android-studio-and-gradle)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

> Steps to import Module in Android Studio 3.3 and lower.

1. Go to **File** >> **New** >> **Import Module...**
2. Select the source directory of the Module you want to import and click Finish.
3. Open Project Structure and open Module Settings for your project.
4. Open the Dependencies tab.
5. Click the (+) icon and select Module Dependency. Select the module and click Ok.
6. Open your `build.gradle` file and check that the module is now listed under dependencies.`implementation project(path: ':ViewPagerIndicator')`

> Steps to import Module in Android Studio 3.4 and higher (See attached
> image).

1. Go to **File** >> **New** >> **Import Module...**
2. Select the source directory of the Module you want to import and click Finish.
3. Open Project Structure Dialog (You can open the PSD by selecting **File > Project Structure**) and from the left panel click on **Dependencies**.
4. Select the module from the **Module**(Middle) section In which you want to add module dependency.
5. Click the (+) icon from the **Declared Dependencies** section and click **Module Dependency**.
6. Select the module and click Ok.
7. Open your `build.gradle` file and check that the module is now listed under dependencies.`implementation project(path: ':ViewPagerIndicator')`
   [image]

Comment: file>>>NEW>>>>import...  That NEW is so important in latest version

Comment: @Shekhar Sir can you take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57779798/add-module-dependency-for-imported-module-shows-blank-screen
thank you for your time.

Comment: I am unable to find Module Dependency in the dropdown. Only Library dependency and JAR dependency are available. What should I do? (Android Studio 4.1.2)

Comment: It doesn't work. If I go to File > New > Import Module, it wants me to import an entire project, but I just need to import one Java file.

Comment: @DonaldDuck, what is your question. If you want to import just one java file, then just do copy paste. 
The above procedure I wrote is to "Import a Module".

Answer (score 10):

1. Click on `File` and select `Import Module option`.
2. Open of select your `ViewPagerIndicator` module from local.
3. add `compile project(path: ':ViewPagerIndicator')` in your gradle file.

Comment: Error:Dependency DialoFragmentdemo:app:unspecified on project ViewPagerIndicator-Library resolves to an APK archive which is not supported as a compilation dependency. File: C:\Users\Saurabhk\DialoFragmentdemo\app\build\outputs\apk\app-release-unsigned.apk

Comment: @Mehul Kabaria Sir can you take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57779798/add-module-dependency-for-imported-module-shows-blank-screen
thank you for your time.

Answer (score 10):

To import an existing Java library to an android project. Do the following.

[image]

Then select your Java library.

Answer (score 5):

In case you have a **module** in your android project called  **library** for example, and you want to add **this** module as a library to **another module** called **app** for example, in that same android project, here's what just worked for me, add this inside your app module's build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(path: ':library')
}
```

Comment: If you're using Kotlin: `implementation(project(":mylibrary"))` per https://developer.android.com/build/dependencies#kts

Answer (score 4):

I was also facing the same issue. Please make sure below steps

```
1)build.gradle :-
     implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation project(path: ':<Project-name>')

2) settings.gradle
     include ':<Project-name>'
```

Answer (score 3):

This [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GdQIHJ_ZDw) will help you to do easily that without any code in `build.gradle` (*actually system will do code for you*).

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to File > New > Project Structure
2. In the left you see Dependencies, click on it
3. All Modules need to be chosen
4. Click + and Library Dependency
5. Search module that you need