# How to change border color and close / delete button for Material Chip View?

Tags: android, android-chips

I'm using **Material Chip View**. Is there anyway for me to change the chip border colour and the remove / delete chip button?

> **Material Chip View** https://github.com/robertlevonyan/materialChipView

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: @pix i tried changing directly to it's library... but it was read.only .. I'm new to android native development. I'm not family with using library and this is my first attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I referred your given lib.

You can easily change remove/delete button by replacing its image from library (named 'ic_close.png').

and for adding a border you need to change code of `Chip.java` like,

```
private void initTypedArray(AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray ta = getContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.Chip, 0, 0);

        chipText = ta.getString(R.styleable.Chip_mcv_chipText);
        hasIcon = ta.getBoolean(R.styleable.Chip_mcv_hasIcon, false);
        chipIcon = ta.getDrawable(R.styleable.Chip_mcv_chipIcon);
        closable = ta.getBoolean(R.styleable.Chip_mcv_closable, false);
        selectable = ta.getBoolean(R.styleable.Chip_mcv_selectable, false);
        backgroundColor = ta.getColor(R.styleable.Chip_mcv_backgroundColor, ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorChipBackground));
        selectedBackgroundColor = ta.getColor(R.styleable.Chip_mcv_selectedBackgroundColor, ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorChipBackgroundClicked));
        textColor = ta.getColor(R.styleable.Chip_mcv_textColor, ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorChipText));
        selectedTextColor = ta.getColor(R.styleable.Chip_mcv_selectedTextColor, ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorChipTextClicked));
        closeColor = ta.getColor(R.styleable.Chip_mcv_closeColor, ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorChipCloseInactive));
        selectedCloseColor = ta.getColor(R.styleable.Chip_mcv_selectedCloseColor, ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorChipCloseClicked));
        cornerRadius = (int) ta.getDimension(R.styleable.Chip_mcv_cornerRadius, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.chip_height) / 2);
        strokeSize = (int) ta.getDimension(R.styleable.Chip_mcv_strokeSize, 2);
        strokeColor = ta.getColor(R.styleable.Chip_mcv_strokeColor, ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorChipCloseClicked));
        iconText = ta.getString(R.styleable.Chip_mcv_iconText);
        iconTextColor = ta.getColor(R.styleable.Chip_mcv_iconTextColor, ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorChipBackgroundClicked));
        iconTextBackgroundColor = ta.getColor(R.styleable.Chip_mcv_iconTextColor, ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorChipCloseClicked));

        ta.recycle();
    }
```

And you need to change color from, `<color name="colorChipCloseClicked">#F5F5F5</color>`

to `<color name="colorChipCloseClicked">#D32F2F</color>`

it will be look like this,

[image]

Hope this helps you!!

Comment: @hibiki ryou have you imported this lib as a module in your Android Studio Project..?

Comment: imported how? i'm called it using gradle

Comment: follow these steps from link to import your lib as module :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41764338/importing-module-in-android-studio