# Offline sdk file for Android Studio

Tags: android, google-developers-console

Peace be upon to you
 Please help me
 I downloaded offline sdk zip file "151"mb , because my network is very slow and hard to download itself.
 What next steps must I do , to work Android studio and sdk normally on widows 10 
Thank you

Comment: https://github.com/MagicMicky/FreemiumLibrary/wiki/Import-the-library-in-Android-Studio


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41764338/importing-module-in-android-studio


it may help you

Answer (score 0):

Simple!

In Android Studio go to:

1. File -> project Structure into Project Structure
2. Left -> SDK Location
3. SDK location select Android SDK location

As shown at: [Android Studio SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpVqf.png)

Comment: I don't understand you , please can you explain with screenshots ?

Comment: Put your downloaded SDK in somewhere like C:\Android\SDK then open Android Studio and set the SDK path to this path. I updated the answer with a screenshot.

Comment: Ok Million Thanks , my Friend.

Comment: @aboaldrdaaa2 If it helped you, mark this answer as correct, please.