# How to import google vr sdk into my Android studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, google-vr-sdk

I want to import the Google VR SDK into my Android Project

I have gvr-android-sdk-1.150.0 downloaded from github

Can someone provide me with in depth steps if possible ?

Comment: you have a jar/aar ? if so read this [Importing Module in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41764338/importing-module-in-android-studio)

Comment: I have imported all the modules but when I go to module dependencies
It's empty

Comment: I added all the aar files in my project as modules.
But only a few turn up in the project structure