# Adding Google Cameraview to a Project

Tags: android, android-camera, camera-view

I'm creating android camera app . I tried to use the camera library in my app to avoid writing plenty lines of code . I found google cameraview on Github (https://github.com/google/cameraview/) . I downloaded it as a zip file . But I don't know how to add to my project as a library. I googled it but couldn't find the exact answer .

Comment: Hello, I strongly recommand you to have a look to this page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contributors/developers of this repo has provided a full project to work as a sample allowing you to understand how the project works.

Firstly, I recommend you to start learning about what is Android module and/or library and how to create and use one.

Then by looking at the project of this repo,Start by looking at project's `settings.gradle` file, you will find that this project consists of two modules:

- the `:library` which is obviously the core lib module
- the `:demo` which is a demo or testing application

Then by looking at the `demo/build.gradle` you will find this statement:

```
compile project(':library')
```

which means that the `library` module is a dependency for the `demo` module.

---

**In short**: you should add the core lib module to your own project and start using it with same steps like what developers did in the docs and/or sample (demo) project.

---

resources:

[Create an Android library - Official docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library)

[Importing Module in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41764338/importing-module-in-android-studio)