# Unable to add imported module as dependency in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv

I am trying to import the OpenCV SDK in Android Studio. I can import the module into my project just fine and it shows up in the project structure. However, once I try to add that module as a dependency in my project, the window gives me no option to select the imported module. In the attached screenshot, the module I am trying to import is named "java".

[image]

Comment: Which module you are trying to add? I can't see OpenCV on the list?

Comment: The module is java. For whatever reason, it didn't give me the prompt to rename the module.

Comment: Check this out, looks like it will help you -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41764338/importing-module-in-android-studio/41764421

Comment: @AnujSharma I did all the steps that the answer you linked said. I just can't seem to find the module anywhere when I get the prompt to add a new module.