# Error when using multi module app with compose

Tags: java, android, android-jetpack-compose, multi-module

i'm having an issue when importing my module as a lib to my main project.

My main project is in Java, and my module is made with Jetpack Compose.

I need that when the user click a button in the java app, it open an activity in the Compose Module.

But when I call the activity from the module, that error occurs:

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVE1N.jpg)

Anyone knows what i have to do?
Please help

Answer (score 0):

It cannot find the classes , maybe it's not properly imported . Look at this link(https://stackoverflow.com/a/41764425/20812539).