# Importing module in Android Electric Eel

Tags: java, android, gradle, import, module

I can't seem to import a gradle project into my android studio project. Other solutions from similar questions have been unsuccessful.

Most applicable question I attempted to follow
[Importing Module in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41764338/importing-module-in-android-studio)

Steps Taken: 
File -> New -> Import Module
Navigate to Project Structure -> Dependencies -> app -> Declared Dependencies

I have two opens in the Dependencies list:

> All Modules

> app

Issue:
There are only two options to adding Declared Dependencies instead of Module Dependency:

> Library Dependency

> JAR/AAR Dependency

I attempted to add as a library dependency but the search yields nothing.

Attempting to use the import was unsuccessful.
Calling classes and functions directly and import all returned errors

What am I missing?