# Dependency on Android Studio

Tags: android

How to import this dependency type into Android Studio?

Lib: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.viewpagerindicator</groupId>
  <artifactId>library</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.1</version>
  <type>apklib</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You could download the project from github and build it as a .jar file and then import it. Or you can use the following: https://github.com/MagicMicky/FreemiumLibrary/wiki/Import-the-library-in-Android-Studio

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using ViewPagerIndicator library with Android Studio and Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130003/using-viewpagerindicator-library-with-android-studio-and-gradle)

Comment: Are you really sure to use it? The last commit is 6 years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is available as a Gradle dependency from JitPack.

To add JitPack repository, add following in your root `build.gradle` file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Then add the dependency in module

```
dependencies {
        ...
        compile 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'
}
```

For more information visit [this](https://jitpack.io/#JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/2.4.1/aar).

Comment: getting exception as  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #346: Binary XML file line #346: Error inflating class com.viewpagerindicator.LinePageIndicator  and error at setViewPager equired type:
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
Provided:
androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager

Answer (score 1):

In AndroidStudio you can simply paste the above XML into your build.gradle `dependency` section and it will convert it to the **gradle** format as seen below.

```
compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1'
```

However if you are using the android gradle plugin 3.0+ you should change `compile` to `implementation`

Comment: getting exception as  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #346: Binary XML file line #346: Error inflating class com.viewpagerindicator.LinePageIndicator  and error at setViewPager equired type:
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
Provided:
androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager